# What is the purpose of limited_ids_for instance method in ruby? Why and How to use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Unable to find how to use limited_ids_for instance method in ruby?

Comment: This is not a ruby method. It's a Rails method. Big difference there.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [`private`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/limited_ids_for) method, you shouldn't use it.